# How to print result from sql-query result?

Tags: php, sql

I have a query like this:

```
"SELECT product.title, SUM(order_product.item_count) AS total
 FROM `order_product` 
    INNER JOIN product ON product.id=order_product.product_id 
WHERE order_product.updated BETWEEN '$startInterval' 
  AND '$endInterval' 
  AND order_product.status=5 
GROUP BY order_product.product_id"
```

and i carried out successfully. Then i fetched the result to an object. The trouble here is when i try to print "SUM(order_product.item_count)" value like this:

```
 foreach ($revenue as $value):     ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $value->title ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"> **<?= $value->SUM(order_product.item_count) ?>**</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

it returns error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::SUM() in "; 
Help me, i tried many way like alias sql but it doesn work.

Here is the result after query:

```
<?php
    var_dump($revenue);
    if(isset($revenue)):
    foreach ($revenue as $value):     ?>
       <?= $value->title ?>
        <?= $value->total ?>

    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

    array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["title"]=> string(7) "1234123" ["SUM(order_product.item_count)"]=> string(6) "123123" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { ["title"]=> string(8) "tresadas" ["SUM(order_product.item_count)"]=> string(3) "999" } }
```

p/s: fixed!

Comment: $value->total ?

Comment: your title work ?

Comment: because the result depend on how you defined your object

Comment: Show us the code you use to get from a query coded in a string literal to a variable called `$revenue`

Comment: Thats not the result from the SQL you posted !!!!!!

Comment: ???? @RiggsFolly what ???

Comment: You posted a comment that I replied to, but now you have removed the comment

Comment: Oh you edited the question. So comment still stands. Your query applies an alias to `SUM(order_product.item_count) AS total` calling the column  `total` therefore there should not be anything in the resultset called `["SUM(order_product.item_count)"]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sorry. my mistake, but i edited. :)

Comment: So the code you post does not match the result you say you get. Tell us the **truth, and nothing but the truth** or we will all disappear in a puff of magic smoke

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's the truth :o, then i must to post result in here for help :o , i have a knowledge in sql so when i have this error, i'm so embarrasing plz

Comment: **My last try** Post ALL the relevant code, That is all the code from the query thru executing the query, thru unloading the result set, and generating whatever output from the result set!!!!!

Comment: how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly let me explain:

Comment: That query i put in switch case with 12 condition, each condition have the same query like i post, it use to calculate something in my project and use to return a result when i choose number from 1->12. When i tried to edit that query as added "AS total", i forget to add it to 11 queries others. So i have the trouble liek i posted. Sr. It's the truth

Comment: **LIKE I SAID The code you showed us does not match the results you say you are getting.** ___A complete waste of all our time___

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `<?= $value->SUM(order_product.item_count) ?>` to `<?= $value->total) ?>`. This is because you aliased the `SUM(order_product.item_count)` to `total` in your query.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$value->total
```

you defined it in your MySQL Query as `total` so you can use it in your Result Object